# How to reopen app correctly from foreground service?

Tags: android, service, android-lifecycle, android-context, intentservice

I've been facing a problem for a while regarding startActivity(intent). What i'm developing is a kind of key word detection like "ok google" that triggers an alert when the user says the word. To achieve that when the user is not using the app i have a LifecycleService that runs in foreground and listens to the user. When the user says the word and the app is killed it opens the activity i need using startActivity from the service, but the problem is that if i keep listening and change to other activity (using the app normally) the detection works (because i hear the sound i put when the word is recognized) but the app doesn't start the activity it should (although the startActivity(intent) is called). I'm pretty sure that the problem has to be with the context that maybe is not the correct one when i open the app with startActivity from the service, but i don't know how to fix it. I tried to user some other variables like applicationContext or the androidContext() from Koin but it is not working.

```
class SpeechRecognitionService : LifecycleService() {

  ...
  //onStartCommand starts the audio recognizer and startAlert() is triggered when the alert is recognized. It is always correctly called


  private fun startAlert() {
        //This is not showing MainActivity although i execute it
        startActivity(MainActivity.getDialogIntent(this))

        //I always hear this audio when the app detects word
        val audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alert_detected_audio)
        audio.start()
    }
}
```

The MainActivity.getDialogIntent(this) is just a common Intent

```
fun getDialogIntent(context: Context): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intent.putExtra(SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG_KEY, true)
        return intent
}
```

The problem only happens if the app is started with the voice recognition (after being killed). If i for example kill the app but open the app again pressing the app icon it works correctly. If i start the app with voice (so, from the startActivity i have above) i worked that time and open the app but when i change to other activity it fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a proper "launcher `Intent`". The easiest way to get one is to call

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager()
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name")
```

Use this `Intent` to start your `MainActivity` instead of calling `MainActivity.getDialogIntent(this)`